# Scaling data real time for LibSVM

Tags: svm, scaling, libsvm, feature-extraction

I am using LibSVM to classify data. I train and test the classifier with linearly scaled feature data on the interval [-1 1]. After establishing a model which produces acceptable accuracy, I want to classify new data which arrives periodically, almost in real time.

I don't know how to rescale the feature columns of the 'real time' data on an interval of [-1 1] since I'm only generating 1 row of features for this input data. If I were to store the min/max values of the testing/training set data feature columns (in order to scale new data), this presents the possibility that if the new real time data does not fall into this min/max range, thus the model is no longer valid as I would have to re-scale all prior data to accommodate for the new min/max and generate a new model.

I have thought about using other scaling techniques such as mean normalization, but I have read that SVM works particularly well with linearly scaled features so I am hesitant to apply another methodology.

How does one deal with the rescaling of new features to a linear interval, when the new features are a single row vector, and could have higher/lower feature values than the max/min feature values used in rescaling the training data?

This is the equation I'm using to rescale the training/testing feature set.

[image: Scoure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling]

Even if one were to use another feature scaling technique (such as mean normalization), with each additional 'real time' classification, would it be prudent to recalculate the mean, min and max for ALL (new, test and train) data before rescaling, or is it acceptable to use the stored scaling values from training/testing for new samples -- until a "re-training" the classifier to account for all the newly acquired data were to occur.

All in all, I think what I'm having trouble with is: how does one deal with linear feature scaling in an 'online' classification problem?

Comment: You have to use the scaling that you generated and used in the training process.